# How to find m + 1000 th prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have prime number $ 2^{204}+7 $. Let denote this prime number as m-th prime number. I would like to find  $m + 10000$ th prime number. Is there any efficient algorithm which I can use?

Comment: I am afraid that there is no better way than brute force :-( You can estimate the value by means of the Prime Number Theorem, but you will not know the exact $m$.

Comment: The only way to find the next prime even, is by simply checking all consecutive integers and verifying if they are prime. Obviously there are ways to speed this up, for instance not checking evens and so forth.

Comment: $2^{204}+1405873$, in case you wonder :)

Answer (score 0):

By the prime number theorem, about $1$ in $204 \log 2 \approx 141$ numbers of that size are prime.  If you skip the ones that are multiples of $2$ or $3$ you should have to text about $470000$ numbers.  The Fermat primality test will eliminate most of the composites.  If you want to be exact, you need to use one of the definitive tests, which are rather slower.